# Can't get write.csv or write.table to work in r editor of BlueSky Statistics

Tags: r, export-csv

Any pointer or hints? Most common r commands do work but not this one!
Have tried write.csv and write.table

Comment: What is the issue, precisely? Error or warning message? Unexpected or no output? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is BlueSky Statistics installs in the program files directory where you don't have permissions to write to. Write your files to the documents directory by specifying the path parameter in the write.csv comand