# In Bluesky Statistics How do I write output to a csv file

Tags: r

I can't get `write.csv` or `write.table` to work in the r editor of BlueSky Statistics.

I usually just use this format in RStudio and it works perfectly.

```
write.csv(df, "zzz.csv")
```

Any hints?"

Comment: This seems similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56034242/89482), where we asked for clarification and don't have any as yet. What, precisely, do you mean by "can't get to work" ?

Answer (score 0):

The default install location for BlueSky Statistics is 'C:\Program Files', where by default, there is no write permission (for creating or deleting files). Also, saving a file in the install location is not safe, as the file may get lost/deleted when the application is uninstalled. So it is always good to save your file(s) in your own folder(s) where you also have write permission.

In short, try to provide a writable location/path in write.csv() or other similar functions/commands.
See example below:

To save your file to the Desktop folder.

```
write.csv(df, "C:/Users/<YourUsername>/Desktop/zzz.csv")
```

Note: use forward slash(/) as a path separator.